# Warning : spi_register_board_info undefined

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to write a spi kernel module.However i get a warning that i am unable to resolve.

`WARNING: "spi_register_board_info" undefined!`

And Whenever i try to load the module, it displays the error "Unknown symbol in the module".Even though symbol exist , when i checked /proc/kallsyms

Output of cat /proc/kallsyms | grep spi_register_board_info

`c09e58c8 T spi_register_board_info`

init function:

```
    #include "header.h"
    #include "declaration.h"
    #include "spiop.h"


    MODULE_AUTHOR("Vijay");
    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

    static struct spi_driver Vijay_spi =
    {
    .driver=
    {
            .name="Vijay_spi_driver",
        },
     .id_table=myid_table,
    .probe=spi_probe,
    .remove=spi_remove
};

static struct spi_board_info myspi_board_info []  __initdata = {
{
    .modalias="Vijay_spi",
    .max_speed_hz=14000000,
    .bus_num=0,
    .chip_select=3,
    .mode=SPI_MODE_0,
},
/*  {
        .modalias="spidev",
        .chip_select=0,
        .max_speed_hz=1*100*100,
        .bus_num=1,
        .mode=SPI_MODE_0,
    },*/
};


struct spi_driver *mydriver;

static int __init init_func(void)
{


    if(spi_register_board_info(myspi_board_info,ARRAY_SIZE(myspi_board_info)) == -1)
    {
        pr_err("spi_register_board_infofailed \n");
        goto OUT;
    }
#ifndef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Begin \n",__func__);
#endif
    mydriver=&Vijay_spi;

    if(spi_register_driver(mydriver) == -1)
    {
        pr_err("spi_register_driver failed \n");
        goto OUT;
    }

#ifndef DEBUG
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s: End \n",__func__);
#endif
    return 0;

OUT:
    return -1;
}
```

Content of header.h :-

```
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/spi/spi.h>
#include<linux/device.h>
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/mutex.h>
#include<linux/mod_devicetable.h>
```

Can somebody shed some light as to why i am getting this warning.

Comment: Because there is no function called `spi_register_board_info`? Did you link the .c file where it is defined?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `#include <linux/spi/spi.h>`.

Comment: in header.h i have included the neceesary header files including <linux/spi/spi.h>

Comment: I'm pretty sure that function isn't exported by the kernel, so can't be used in an external module.

Comment: The warning is produced by the MODPOST part of the module build process because the `spi_register_board_info` symbol is not exported for use by loadable kernel modules. You can only call it for built-in kernel code, and even then, hardly anything uses it these days.

Comment: @Ian  can you suggest an alternate function for spi_register_board_info

Comment: You just shouldn’t use it in the *driver*. There are at least three possible options: a) ACPI; b) Device Tree; c) legacy (and not recommended) board files or platform code.